# Fazer outra frase aparecer no mesmo lugar que a anterior, após uma animação

Tags: javascript, html, aplicação-web

É o seguinte, preciso que uma frase apareça como se estivesse sido digitada na tela, e após a primeira frase aparecer por completo, deve surgir uma nova da mesma forma que a anterior. A parte de aparecer o texto, já foi feita, mas não sei como implementar a parte de substituição de frase. Alguém tem alguma ideia de como isso possa ser feito?

```js
function typeWriter(elemento) {
    const textoArray = elemento.innerHTML.split('');
    elemento.innerHTML = '';
    textoArray.forEach((letra, i) => {
        setTimeout(() => elemento.innerHTML += letra, 75 * i);
  });
}

const titulo = document.querySelector('.fundo-roxo');
typeWriter(titulo);
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
  <h1 class="titulo-linha-1"><span class="fundo-roxo">Texto 1.</span></h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode resolver isso com uma função chamada [Slice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp), tendo duas variáveis uma para manter o texto e outra que vai alterar, e fazendo um `loop` para que seja possível tratar tratar essa variável, etão seu código ficaria parecido com algo assim:

Primeiro separaria duas variáveis para tratar sendo que a primeira ficaria vazia e a segunda com o texto que não vai ser alterado.

```
var textoTratar = '';
var textCompleto = 'Texto 1.';
```

Para escrever você poderia pegar uma letra por vez dessa variável e adicionando aos poucos.

```
//Escrever
for (var i = 0; i < textCompleto.length; i++) {

    //console.log(i);

    textoTratar += textCompleto.slice(i, i + 1);

    document.getElementById('alpha').innerHTML = textoTratar;

}
```

E para apagar você pode fazer o processo reverso, pegando o próprio texto e removendo uma letra de cada vez

```
//Apagar
for (var i = 0; i < textCompleto.length; i++) {

    //console.log(i);

    textoTratar = textoTratar.slice(0, textoTratar.length - 1);

    document.getElementById('alpha').innerHTML = textoTratar;

}
```

**NOTA:** eu fiz o `loop` com um `for`, mas você pode utilizar o tipo de `loop` que você preferir, pois o `for` vai ser muito rápido e não vai dar para ver o efeito de escrever na tela.